# Removing an element from a type asserted Slice of interfaces

Tags: go, interface, slice, type-assertion

In Golang, after asserting to a slice, how is one able to remove an element from said slice?

For example, the following returns the error `cannot assign to value.([]interface {})`

```
value.([]interface{}) = append(value.([]interface{})[:i],value.([]interface{})[i+1:]...)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have a slice value wrapped in an interface, you can't change it. You can't change *any* value wrapped in interfaces.

When an interface value is created to wrap a value, a copy is made and stored in the interface.

When you type-assert it, you get a copy of the value, but you can't change the value *in* the interface. That's why it's not allowed to assign a value to it, as if it would be allowed, you would only assign a new value to a copy (that you acquire as the result of the type assertion). But the value stored in the interface would **not** be changed.

If this is indeed something you want, then you must store a slice pointer in the interface, e.g. `*[]interface{}`. This doesn't change the fact that you can't change the value in the interface, but since this time it's a pointer, we don't want to change the pointer but the *pointed* value (which is the slice value).

See this example demonstrating how it works:

```
s := []interface{}{0, "one", "two", 3, 4}

var value interface{} = &s

// Now do the removal:
sp := value.(*[]interface{})

i := 2
*sp = append((*sp)[:i], (*sp)[i+1:]...)

fmt.Println(value)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oL5v8CsUZo)):

```
&[0 one 3 4]
```

As you can see, we removed the element at index `2` which was `"two"` which is now "gone" from the result when printing the interface value.